# How to convert a binary row vector to a normal row vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a binary row vector e.g.

> b = dec2bin(15)

This vector behaves badly when I try to multiply it component-wise with a 'normal' vector. How do I convert b to a normal vector?

To be more specific, if

> d = [1 2 3 4]

I want

> n = d.*b

to give me [1 2 3 4], but it instead gives [49    98   147   196].

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that dec2bin returns a **string**, not a number vector. You have to convert the char array to a numeric array, and you could do that with **arrayfun**, like this:

```
b = dec2bin(15);
b_numeric = arrayfun(@(x) str2num(x), b);
n = d.*b_numeric;
```

If you have the communications system toolbox, you already have a function that does exactly that, the `de2bin`

Answer (score 5):

`str2num` will work, but since you're guaranteed just a single digit in each cell, you can try

```
b = dec2bin(15) - 48;
```

which should be much faster.

Note: 48 is the ASCII code for the character "0".

Comment: Better answer than my poor effort.  I still think it's an odd way to multiply a vector by 1.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I think the assumption is that `b` is variable, not always [1 1 1 1].

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that `dec2bin` returns an array of characters.  When you perform the element-wise multiplication by your array `d` you get the results of multiplying `d` element-wise by the ASCII code for the character '1', which is 49.

If you want to multiply `d` by the array `[1 1 1 1]` this seems like a convoluted approach.  So what are you really trying to do ?

To convert a character (array) to a number you would use the `str2num` function.  Here it would convert the string '1111' to the number 1111 so `str2num(dec2bin(15))` returns `1111`.